# code inside an include.php not detecting a variable defined on the main page

Tags: php

I'm having some problem with a variable not taken into account by an include located deeper in the page.

To be more specific, here is what the main page in question looks like :

```
<!-- Determine User's permissions on current directory -->

<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory
    $getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            return true;
        }

        $scan_result = scanDirectory($folder, $directory);

        if($scan_result) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

if ((gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
        $getprivileges = true;
    }
?>




...code




...more code




<?php include('file-to-include.php') ?>
```

The variable in question is `$getprivileges` and is defined by the function in this code. `$getprivileges` is defined at the top of my page, and is called several times throughout the page.

In the middle of the page I have an `include` which contains functions that requiere to verify the value of `$getprivileges`, exept it cannot. The code inside the include behaves like the variable wasn't defined, or did not exist.

And it happens only for the code inside this include, the rest of the main page is fine and wherever i call `$getprivileges` no matter if it's located above or below the include it works well.

Why doesn't the code inside the included file detect my variable `$getprivileges` ?

How can I get it to work properly ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

-apatik

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but... If you want to use a variable inside a function that was defined outside of the function, you must use `global $variable` inside the function in order to access the "global $variable". sometimes php makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the responses, Fred i'll check this out, @dan08  as mentionned the variable is already being used all over the page and out of the function, it just doesn't work in the case a part of my code in the page is being included (<? php include() ?>) instead of being directly typed in the page

Comment: @Fred , indeed I got this error [ Undefined variable: getprivileges in C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\include\views\main_filelist.php on line 11 ] (main_filelist.php being the file included in my main page) so it appears that it cannot detect my $getprivileges variable

Comment: then as stated, try and make it a global accessed variable; it's a variable scope issue. You're executing your code above, then "including" the file after.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, going to check out how to do that and I'll try it

Comment: Also, adding `print_r(get_defined_vars())` in different places might be helpful for troubleshooting

Comment: Sounds like a cool functionnality, I'll try this yes, even tho I'm already pretty sure where the variable stops being defined

Comment: I tried simply defining the variable outside of the function but it still doesn't work even tho it is now global :/

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Thanks for your answer, I actually did the suggestions of your second comment earlier but it still wouldn't get me the variable when the file is included. After investigations I may have found where it comes from but I will have to open a new thread since it looks to be way more complicated than a simple include/variable problem

Comment: I wish that was that :( but no I am not, I'm currently grabbing as much informations as I can to make a new thread, but to resume the file included is not actually included in a classic way, it's included though what appear to be a function

Comment: Actually no ! It looks like this : Index.php -> include1 -> include2 (my main page) -> include3 (where the global variable won't work) edit: But the fact severals includes are involved doesn't seem to be a trouble, only in this specific case.

Comment: Ok - declare any $GLOBAL variable in the outer includes and find out where they aren't seen or can be seen? Create a very simple set of scripts that duplicate what you think is the current structure of includes. test it. Then start to see where your current structure fails?

Comment: Yes that's what I did for testing, and the variable was working. Unfortunately if I move the include outside of the function then most of the scripts stops working due to some weird parameters. I will link you the new thread once it is made, in the evening, if you want to take a look

Comment: sounds interesting ;-/ We need to see some actual, _simplified_ code: 1) In the 'included script` that isn't working. 2) The script that includes it. I suspect in setting this up you will most likely find the error.

Comment: @ Ryan Vincent I posted the new thread with all the details if you want to take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576511/global-variable-not-being-defined-in-a-gibberish-include