# global variable not being defined in a gibberish include

Tags: php

***Resume :***
I (php beginner) am having a problem where a `global variable` is not getting defined in a specific include `gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)` that seems to be a function. Others includes on the same don't have this problem. **//**

I'm using a File Manager called FileGator on my website.

In this File Manager there is file called `main.php` which is the page every users are on when they want to navigate through the folders or upload/download/manipulate files.

Now this `main.php` file includes several others php files (for configurations, templates, tables...).
Also in this `main.php` file, at the very beggining of the file, I have a function that defines a **global variable called $getprivileges**.

part of `main.php` :

```
<!-- Determine User's permissions on current directory -->

<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory
    $getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            return true;
        }

        $scan_result = scanDirectory($folder, $directory);

        if($scan_result) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

if ((gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
        $getprivileges = true;
    }
?>


...code


...more code


<?php gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)?>


...code again
```

Since my variable `$getprivileges` is global and located at the top of the file it is supposed to be taken into account by every others includes in this page, and it does for every of the includes exept one.

FileGator doesn't includes his files the classic way it looks since the include that causes me troubles has this shape : `<?php gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)?>`

After some digging to find out the meaning of this gibberish (note that FileGator doesn't provide advanced support any longer and that the ressources of the FAQ are limited in my problem) here are the informations I could gather to try solving this :

`gator::display()` looks to be a function defined in a file named file-gator.php, which is also the page that generates my `main.php` file (for instance if I am not logged in it can displays login.php instead).
Here is what I could find about `gator::display()` in this `file-gator.php` :

```
<?php>
    class gator {
           public static function display($view, $params = null){
                require_once gatorconf::get('base_path')."/include/views/".$view;
           }
    }
<?>
```

And here is a part of `main_filelist.php` so you can see what $params is used for :

```
<table class="file-list">
<?php $i = 1;?>

    <tbody>

    <?php if(!empty($params['dirs'])) foreach ($params['dirs'] as $file):?>
    <?php if (($file['name'] == "user") && ($_SESSION['cwd'] == gatorconf::get('repository'))):?>
    <?php else:?>
        <tr class="directory <?php if ($file['type'] == "back") echo 'back-button';?>">

          <?php if ($getprivileges == true): ?>
            <?php if ($file['type'] != 'back' && $file['type'] != 'user'):?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $i++;?>" value="<?php echo $file['crypt']?>" /></td>
            <?php elseif ($file['type'] == 'user'):?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><a class="user" href="?cd=<?php echo $file['link']?>"></a></td>
            <?php else:?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><a class="back" href="?cd=<?php echo $file['link']?>"></a></td>
            <?php endif;?>
          <?php else:?>
            <?php if ($file['type'] != 'back' && $file['type'] != 'user'):?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><a class="folder" href="?cd=<?php echo $file['link']?>"></a></td>
            <?php elseif ($file['type'] == 'user'):?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><a class="user" href="?cd=<?php echo $file['link']?>"></a></td>
            <?php else:?>
            <td class="chkboxes"><a class="back" href="?cd=<?php echo $file['link']?>"></a></td>
            <?php endif;?>
          <?php endif;?>
```

So it looks like the file main_filelist.php included on my main.php is included through a require_once function (`gatorconf::get('base_path')` is just the installation path of the file manager) exept this `require_once function` is apparently inside the function `public static function display` with a variable `$param` on top of the require_once...

I am positive that this is the reason why my variable does not work for the code being included by this function.

If I remplace `gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)` by  `gator::display("main_filelist.php")` most of the code won't work.

But if I replace `gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)` by a classic include `include('main_filelist.php')` then the most of the code is executed and I can actually see my variable `$getprivileges` being taken into account.

- Why is my variable `$getprivileges` not working with this type of
  include ? (debugging reports me that the variable is not defined for
  the code included by `gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params)` )
- How can I have my variable to work without changing the way it is
  included with the `$params` ? (I am afraid to break the code and
  there is the possibility that I have to do it for another file in the
  future on which I may not have the choice)

Sorry for the lenght of this post, I am trying to give as much informations as possible and I'm actually figuring a lot out by recapitulating this situation.

Also, I am a beginner in php so feel free to give as much details as you want if you have some suggestions :s Thanks a lot for your help !

-apatik

**Update :**

I added this code on the `main-filelist.php` (the included file that wouldn't get my `$getprivilege` and so far it looks ok ! Going to test every possibilities.

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      
    $getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory); 

    if ((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
        $getprivileges = true;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is it a question or an article?

Comment: Try to summarise the question in the title or add a short paragraph to summarise it at the start for those who just want to know the main parts.

Comment: it's indeed a question, I just added a lot of informations to get a solution. I'll edit a resumate

Comment: The require occurs within a method, i.e. the included script has the scope of that method  ...not the global scope.

Comment: @VolkerK thanks for the answer, the method is the function display or the $param in the function ? Can it be bypassed somehow ?

Comment: `public static function display(...)` - that defines the scope. I'd suggest you add `getprivileges` to the $params array and use it accordingly in your view.

Comment: Allright I understand, unfortunately `$params` is a mystery to me, it doesn't appear anywhere else on the file-gator.php file. Also `$getprivileges` is not defined in the same file than `public static function` display(...)

Comment: Take a look at how $params['dirs'] is used in the view and then search for the code that sets this array element: Do the same with your privilege-values. Could be (and probably is) as simple as `$params['privileges']=$getprivileges;` before `gator::display("main_filelist.php", $params);`.

Comment: Good hint, but for $getprivileges it's actually me that added it to the File Manager (you can see the full function that defines it in my first quote of code). Going to check for thoses $param['dirs'] tho.

Comment: `it's actually me that added it to the File Manager`  - I don't think that matters much ;-) You only have to check whether your changes collide with something already in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope and http://docs.php.net/get_defined_vars and then the output of

```
<?php // test2.php
var_export( get_defined_vars() );
```

and

```
<?php
$globalvar = 1;
require 'test2.php';

class Foo {
    public static function bar($params) {
        $localvar = 2;
        require 'test2.php';
    }
}
echo "\r\n--------------------\r\n";
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar( array('getprivileges'=>'something') );
```

should illustrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check out theses docs because I feel lost hehe, but according to your illustration I feel that the fact that my variable is defined on the main.php file is part of my problem

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't it actually be easier to simply add the function that defines the variable $getprivileges in the main_filelist.php file ? Would it be possible ? The function would then be executed twice when main.php loads (once in main.php and a second time when main_filelist.php gets included), would that work ?

Comment: Once the function is defined it can be called from anwhere, i.e. you could already call it from within the view. But you might want to read up on the concepts of model-view-controller before  doing that.

Comment: I just found a solution 10min ago, I'm still testing it out to see if everthing is fine but so far it looks ok ! As you mentionned my variable was not in the include's scope so I redefined every variables used in my function to define $getprivileges, and then called $getprivileges inside the include, I had to do some weird stuff because some variables could get called and others could not (probably as you said because of the $params somwhere). I'm not entirely sure how, but it worked ! I'm just going to check if everything is good. I will edit my main post with the code I used also in a minute